# Two functions are the same only if the dot product is the same

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

I found this statement on a functional analysis book and I am having trouble to show it.

Let $X,Y$ be Hilbert spaces with dot products $(\cdot,\cdot)_X$ and $(\cdot,\cdot)_Y$ . Let $f,g: X\to Y$ be functions (they must not necessarilly be  linear or continuous). Then
\begin{align*}
f=g \iff \forall x\in X,y \in Y: (f(x),y)_Y=(g(x),y)_Y
\end{align*}
The $\Rightarrow$ direction is trivial. I tried to proof the other direction by contradiction but I did not find a solution.

Comment: I think one of the $y$ needs to be replaced by some other variable (e.g. $z$). Since $\langle \sin(x)-cos(x),y-y\rangle = \langle\sin(x)-\cos(x),0\rangle = 0$, but $\sin\neq\cos$.

Comment: Hint: argue the contrapositive. If $f \neq g$ can you find $x$ and $y$ so that $(fx,y) \neq (gx,y)$? The fact $f \neq g$ furnishes an $x$ with $fx \neq gx$. Do you see how to find a $y$ which finishes the job?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I was thinking $y=f(x)$ for the $x$ with $f(x)\neq g(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If for all $y\in Y$ we have $$(f(x) , y ) =(g(x),y) $$ then by putting $y =f(x) -g(x) $ we get $$0 = (f(x) -g(x) , f(x) - g(x) )= ||f(x) - g(x) ||^2 $$
thus $f(x) =g(x) $ and since we can do it for any $x$ therefore $f=g.$

Comment: +1...............To the proposer: In a Hilbert space $Y$, if $(z,y)=0$ for all $y\in Y$ then $z=0$, as this A shows.